# Creating a credit card input. Why does the form not add dashes to 4 digit credit card?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a credit validation form. The input field no matter what should always be a maximum of 19 digits and have 4 numeric digits separated by a dash. So far I can do it whilst typing but pasting does not work, neither does editing a few numbers, the form does not update.

I do not want to use any plugins and my client only uses MasterCard and Visa that is why they have asked for 19 digits.

So far, I have also tried to put my code in a loop but the loop is still not working on copy and paste and other scenarios

```js
var cc = $('#cc-card');

// start loop
setInterval(function() {

  jQuery(cc).on('propertychange click blur change change keyup keydown paste', function() {

    var cctlength = jQuery(this).val().length;

    // output should always be 0000-0000-0000-0000

    switch (cctlength) {
      case 4:
        var cctVal = jQuery(this).val();
        var cctNewVal = cctVal + '-';
        jQuery(this).val(cctNewVal);
        break;
      case 9:
        var cctVal = jQuery(this).val();
        var cctNewVal = cctVal + '-';
        jQuery(this).val(cctNewVal);
        break;
      case 14:
        var cctVal = jQuery(this).val();
        var cctNewVal = cctVal + '-';
        jQuery(this).val(cctNewVal);
        break;
      default:
        break;

    }

  });

  // end loop
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cc-card" type="text" maxlength="19" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••">
```

Comment: Why not use something like `.replace(/(.{4})/g,"$1-");` Example `"1234567898765432".replace(/(.{4})/g,"$1-").substring(0, 19);`

Comment: don't use set interval for that! yikes!

Comment: @NewToJS I tried it and update it to this; https://jsfiddle.net/1ywb5t3n/3/ - seems to cover everything?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid well that seems to work just fine.. even when you paste into the input.The only issue you will have is updating the input with that new value.

Comment: @NewToJS how can I self update the input field though? See my latest fiddle it just breaks: https://jsfiddle.net/1ywb5t3n/4/

Comment: Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/1ywb5t3n/6/ `.replace(/\D/g,'').replace(/(.{4})/g,"$1-").substring(0, 19);` Also you don't need to set so many events. You can just use `input` to trigger the function as it will cover keyup/keydown/change/paste.

Comment: You cannot copy and paste using CTRL/CMD nor right click and you cannot later on go back and edit digits =) similar to the smart solution by @nem035

Comment: I can copy/paste into the input just fine and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to use `setInterval`, you can just update whenever the input value changed (using the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event).

Secondly, how about anytime a user adds a value, you separate it into chunks of 4 and insert `-` in between?

Finally, every time you read a value you can strip all non-numeric characters which will remove added `-` as well as any other character the user might have added.

*Note*: You must also reset the cursor position in case the user edited a digit before the end of the string because updating a value will automatically move the cursor to the end.

```js
const cc = $('#cc-card');

function chunksOf(string, size) {
  var i, j, arr = [];
  for (i = 0, j = string.length; i < j; i += size) {
    arr.push(string.substring(i, i + size));
  }
  return arr;
}

cc.on('input', function() {
  const elem = cc.get(0);                    // store DOM element ref
  const cursorPosition = elem.selectionEnd;  // remember cursor position

  const value = cc.val().replace(/\D/g, ''); // strip non-numeric chars
  const numberChunks = chunksOf(value, 4);   // split into 4-digit chunks
  const newValue = numberChunks.join('-');   // combine 4-digit chunks into a single string
  cc.val(newValue);                          // update new value

  elem.selectionStart = elem.selectionEnd = cursorPosition + 1; // reset cursor position since the value changed
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Enter Credit Card:</h3>
<input id="cc-card" type="text" maxlength="19" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••">
```

Comment: Your code and logic is really good. But you cannot CTRL/CMD paste in your field so autofill will not work and the user cannot use their cursor to edit between numbers as it replaces others.. I updated my fiddle to this: https://jsfiddle.net/1ywb5t3n/3/

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid I fixed this by using the `input` event. Check out my latest edit

Comment: the only issue still remains that the user cannot use their cursor and edit previous digits 4444-4445-4444-4444 try editing the number 5 and it shifts the cursor type to the end?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid you can reset the cursor position every time, I added an example